# Keras input specification for word2vec vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, word2vec, word-embedding

I read all the other answers regarding this topic, but my use case is slightly different.

I have a numpy array of shape (800,128,1). Each element in the 800 elements stores a word2vec embedding of shape (128,1). Now I wanted to send this as input with batch size 64 to a Keras model with first layer as Input layer. I'm getting the following error:

```
expected party to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (800, 128, 1)
```

I understand that the input layer requires 2 dimensions, but which two? Or should I specify input shape on my own as three dimensional?

The input layer is currently this:

```
Input(shape = (embedding_size, ), name = 'party')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape of input is `(embedding_size,)`, where `embedding_size` is presumably 128. So the input is expected to be an array of shape `(batch_size, embedding_size)`, not `(batch_size, embedding_size, 1)`. You need to reshape your array to omit the last dimension of size 1.

Comment: Thank you. I knew this was the problem - and initially I didn't have that dimension 1. But numpy has this thing that it can't store arrays as elements, so that's why I had to create a 3d array instead. Any way out of this?

Comment: You can your numpy array A of shape (800,128,1) and reshape it using np.reshape or np.squeeze. For example, np.squeeze(A) would do the job. Then you will have an array of shape (800, 128).